# How to find the Average Queue Length and Maximum Queue Length of the Ready Queue?

Tags: algorithm, round-robin

For example, take process `p1,p2,p3,p4,p5` with respective burst time as `6,5,2,3,7` seconds and CPU time quantum 2 seconds.

Can any one tell me how to calculate the average ready queue length and the maximum ready queue length for Round Robin scheduling?

Here Ready Queue => the queue from where we have to en-queue and de-queue during the processes execution.

Actually, I have not got the formula or how to find these parameters anywhere till now. So any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry can you elaborate on 'burst time'?

Comment: burst time means=> completion time of each individual processes if the CPU is allotted to them individually.

Comment: No response,till now!Please, I need it urgently, can any one help please?